# Plotting Pearson Correlation Coefficient with matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, statistics, scipy

I've been able to use the pearsonr function in sciPy to get the correlation coefficient and now want to plot  the result onto a scatter plot using matplotlib.

I looked through the doc's but can't see anything to help with this.

What would be the best way to achieve this.

I'm not a mathematician so this is all very new.

There is a function in Excel that does this.

Thanks

Comment: It does not make a lot of sense to talk about a scatterplot of the correlation coefficient. Do you mean a scatterplot of your dataset instead?

Comment: Yes, I wasn't too sure about that. But a scatter plot of my data would show visually any correlation. So depending on the direction of the plots we could see if it is [-1-0-+1] and that would fit in with the correlation coefficient that the pearsonr function calculated?

Comment: What points do you want this function to be plotted? Could you provide more detail.

Comment: Could you post the data you want to plot for the `x` and `y` for the pearson function?

Comment: Thanks the data wold be x=[50,500,1500,2500]
 and y=[72,414,1,13]

Answer (score -2, accepted):

matplotlib.org has several examples. Here's how you'd get started with your data:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()
x = [50,500,1500,2500];
y = [72,414,1,13]
ax1.plot(x, y, 'bo')
plt.show()
```

And here's a link to the most basic example available:
http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/simple_plot.html

Comment: Thanks for sending the example. I'll take a look at that and at the link.

Comment: This answer doesn't even mention how to calculate the Pearson Correlation Coefficient let alone how to plot it. How is it the accepted answer?

Comment: @xApple that's because the OP's issue wasn't really with the Pearson Correlation Coefficient and the title of the question is poorly worded.

Comment: @xApple this is very clear if you read both the question and the comments that clarified it.